# How do stock target prices work?

Tags: stocks, investing

Why are there two dollar amounts in this price target; that are actually descending?  Can anyone explain this:

This is from a website where I'm doing some research on a stock (I'm intentionally leaving the name of the stock out).

Why are there (2) two values in descending order???

***The price target was set to $9.00 - $7.50***

Comment: Maybe the website you are reading can explain the style choice to put in descending order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means that they *expect* the stock to be somewhere **between** $9 and $7.50. Typically the target timeframe is about 12 to 18 months out, but it may specify the timeframe in the analysis.